# Domain Decomposition with PETSc

Tags: c++, mpi, petsc, metis

Does anyone have any experience on Domain Decomposition using PETSc library? 
I have used PETSc for creating my vectors and matrix within my c++ code. I also used KSP to solve the linear system. 
I used follwoing examples tp learn about DD in PETSc but they were not helpful for me:

http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-3.5/src/snes/examples/tutorials/ex10d/ex10.c.html
http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-3.2/src/snes/examples/tutorials/ex12.c.html
http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/src/snes/examples/tutorials/ex62.c.html​

I would be grateful if you give me some hints on how to do the graph partitioning and domain decomposition with PETSc.

Comment: You might get (better) answers at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com